# Space $C^2(\overline{U})$ for open set $U$

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $U$ be a bounded open domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does the space $C^2(\overline{U})$ (the bar over  $U$ means closure) mean the set of twice-differentiable functions $u$ such that $u, u_t, u_{x_i}$ are continuous on $\overline{U}$?

Or is it something else? If it's not what I think it is, what space of functions do I want to use?

Comment: I think you're pretty much correct apart from the fact that you need all first and second derivatives of $u$ to exist and be continuous.